# Cannot access model property on class definition

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I send value to model as attribute

```
Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.items = new Models.Items()
            .on('sync:subitems', function (item) {
                this.subitems = new Models.Subitems({itemId: item.attributes.id});
```

And successfully receive it in initilize of model

```
var Subitems = Models.Subitems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        this.itemId = attributes.itemId;
        console.log(this.itemId);
    },
    model: Subitem,
    url: './subitems?item_id=' + encodeURIComponent(this.itemId)
});
```

`console.log` returns the value of attribute in initialize.

But request is sent like:

```
'./subitems?item_id=undefined'
```

Why do I have undefined if I have access to the property in initialize? How can it be fixed?

Comment: can you try changing url to a function and see what "this" is? It could be possible that it is the wrong context..

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica That actually is the answer. `this` when building the arguments for the `Backbone.Collection.extend` function call is nothing in particular (so probably `window` in this case), but change `url` to a function and `this` should be the right thing.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a context issue, thanks for the verification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change url to a function and you'll be in the context of the backbone collection as appose to the window.